# Is there an easier way to show that this set is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have to show that a certain set is measurable. I believe I found a way, but I believe my solution is overly complicated. I am wondering if there is a simpler method? Ideally, if you could, I would greatly appreciate it if you could mention the thinking process and/or comment on my own.

> Let $(f_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of measurable functions from $X \to \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Show that the following set is measurable:
> $$S = \{ x \in X | (f_n(x))_{n=0}^{\infty} \text{ converges to a rational } \}$$

**My thinking process:** First, fix a rational $q$. Once we find a way to describe the set of $x$ for which $(f_n(x)) \to q$, we can union over all the rationals and be done.

Now $(f_n(x)) \to q$ means that for every positive integer $m$, the sequence $(f_n(x))$ must "eventually" be in $(q-\frac 1m, q + \frac 1m).$ "Eventually" can be achieved by $\cup \cap$, so so far we have
$$\bigcup_{k \ge 0} \bigcap_{n \ge k} \{ q-\frac 1m < f_n < q+ \frac 1m\}.$$
Now we want this to hold for every $m \ge 1$, and then we want to allow any rational $q$, so the final answer is:
$$\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \bigcap_{m \ge 1} \bigcup_{k \ge 0} \bigcap_{n \ge k} \{ q-\frac 1m < f_n < q+ \frac 1m\}$$
which is clearly measurable.

Comment: This looks fine to me, and I don't think you can make it much simpler if you're working from first principles.  There's a typo in the last line: $f$ should be $f_n$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the feedback! I was hoping that there would be a way to use only 2-3 set operations. This type of reduction happened to me before, and also, the current version would be a bit annoying to prove formally.

Comment: I don't know of any way that's noticeably simpler, and I'll be surprised if there is one.  And the proof is already pretty close to "formal".  All you'd really need to do is spell out your characterization of $f_n(x) \to q$ in the third sentence, and the rest follows by very definition of what union and intersection mean.

Comment: I think your proof is as lean as it gets, but if you want to simplify the final expression, you can fix an $\epsilon > 0$ and drop the intersection over $m$ by looking at $\epsilon$-neighborhoods instead of $\frac{1}{m}$-neighborhoods and conclude by $\epsilon$ being arbitrary. That's the only "simplification" I can think of.

Comment: Thank you both again for your feedback!